# Continuity and Topological Open Regions

Tags: general-topology, continuity, real-numbers

My only familiarity with topology is the basic theory of mereotopology, so apologies is this sounds strange.

An open region is a region without a definite boundary--that is, there is no way to draw a boundary including only points in the region such that every point in the region is inside that boundary. I think of it as the interior of, for example, a polygon without the edges that define the polygon. A closed region includes a definite boundary. The complement of a region is all of the points that are not in the region, so in a normal topological space the complement of a closed region is an open region and vice versa.

This strikes me as related to continuity in the real numbers. If you imagine the real number line as a topological space where a range of numbers is viewed as a region, then an open range is an open region and a closed range is a closed region. In this case, the statement that the complement of an open region is a closed region seems equivalent to the statement that every range has a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound--which is equivalent to continuity of the real numbers.

Does this make sense, and am I right about it?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what's being asked here, but will at least point out that the completeness (not "continuity") of the real numbers is not relevant to the fact that the complement of open is closed. This fact is true for, say, the rationals (or any topological space).